Tizen Studio Debugging Error - Setting the debugging URL
I'm trying to debug my aplication on a TV device (not an emulator), but when I right-click on the project and select Debug As > Tizen Web Application, the app is successfully installed on the tv, but an error dialog is displayed with the message:
"Setting the debugging URL... > Fail
null
Setting the debugging URL... > Fail
Please try one of the following two possible solutions :

If some other app is already running in debug mode, first exit that app and then start debugging your current app.
Restart the target Emulator or TV.
Unknown Error"

Thank you in advance for your help

Hello, have you checked this page? https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-device.html

Hello! Yes, I have seen that page.

I solved this problem by removing the special characters from the <title/> tag in the index.html file.
